# How to replace objects causing import errors with None during pickle load?

Tags: python, pickle, python-import, built-in

I have a pickled structure consisting of nested builtin primitives (list, dictionaries) and instances of classes that are not in the project anymore, that therefore cause errors during unpickling. I do not really care about those objects, I wish I could extract numerical values stored in this nested structure. Is there any way to unpickle from a file and replace everything that was broken due to import issues with, let's say, `None`?

I was trying to inherit from `Unpickler` and override `find_class(self, module, name)` to return `Dummy` if class can not be found, but for some reason I keep getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` in `load reduce` after that.

```
class Dummy(object):
    def __init__(self, *argv, **kwargs):
        pass
```

I tried something like

```
class RobustJoblibUnpickle(Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, _module, name):
        try:
            super(RobustJoblibUnpickle, self).find_class(_module, name)
        except ImportError:
            return Dummy
```

Comment: Are you saying that you could pickle an object but not unpickle it? What's the broader task here?

Comment: @roganjosh that structure (lists of dicts of lists ..) was pickled a while ago and codebase changed significantly since then; now if I try to unpickle it I face import errors because there are no classes like ones used there, though I do not need objects stored there, I'd be fine even with numerical values and strings only; so, yes, the broad problem is that I can not unpickle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can catch the exception in a `try` block, and do what you want (<strike>set some object to `None`</strike> use a Dummy class)?

edit:

Take a look at this, I don't know if it is the right way to do it, but it seems to work fine:

```
import sys
import pickle

class Dummy:
    pass

class MyUnpickler(pickle._Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, module, name): # from the pickle module code but with a try
        # Subclasses may override this. # we are doing it right now...
        try:
            if self.proto < 3 and self.fix_imports:
                if (module, name) in _compat_pickle.NAME_MAPPING:
                    module, name = _compat_pickle.NAME_MAPPING[(module, name)]
                elif module in _compat_pickle.IMPORT_MAPPING:
                    module = _compat_pickle.IMPORT_MAPPING[module]
            __import__(module, level=0)
            if self.proto >= 4:
                return _getattribute(sys.modules[module], name)[0]
            else:
                return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)
        except AttributeError:
            return Dummy

# edit: as per Ben suggestion an even simpler subclass can be used
# instead of the above

class MyUnpickler2(pickle._Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, module, name):
        try:
            return super().find_class(module, name)
        except AttributeError:
            return Dummy

class C:
    pass

c1 = C()

with open('data1.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(c1,f)

del C # simulate the missing class

with open('data1.dat', 'rb') as f:
    unpickler = MyUnpickler(f) # or MyUnpickler2(f)
    c1 = unpickler.load()

print(c1) # got a Dummy object because of missing class
```

Comment: well, you need to somehow do that "inside" the unpickle routine to continue unpickling after replacing an object with `None`

Comment: Yep, I tried something like that, my issue is probably somewhere else; if I understand correctly, it can be done even easier with `super().find_class(self, module, name)` inside `try .. catch` block. But my problem seem to be somewhere else. Thanks for pointing this, though.

Comment: Nice suggestion, +1 for doing it, and just improved my answer code.